# Parsing Paypal Response with javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal

Paypal is returning the following two http responses (one success and one failure).  I sure could use some help figuring out how to parse them using javascript?  So, I need to pull out ACK= "Success" (or "Failure"  and "Date".  THANKS!

SUCCESS:

{"result":{"uuid":"6bd97902-33fd-70d8-8a30-cebd03756d38","status":200,"headers":{"Connection":"close","Content-Length":"104","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Date":"Thu, 13 Mar 2014 20:08:56 GMT","Server":"Apache"},"text":"TIMESTAMP=2014%2d03%2d13T20%3a08%3a56Z&CORRELATIONID=4ed210495e962&ACK=Success&VERSION=93&BUILD=10030158","buffer":[84,73,77,69,83,84,65,77,80,61,50,48,49,52,37,50,100,48,51,37,50,100,49,51,84,50,48,37,51,97,48,56,37,51,97,53,54,90,38,67,79,82,82,69,76,65,84,73,79,78,73,68,61,52,101,100,50,49,48,52,57,53,101,57,54,50,38,65,67,75,61,83,117,99,99,101,115,115,38,86,69,82,83,73,79,78,61,57,51,38,66,85,73,76,68,61,49,48,48,51,48,49,53,56],"cookies":{}}}

AND Failure

{"result":{"uuid":"022f4f52-8caf-deae-fd7b-94daf0d787ad","status":200,"headers":{"Connection":"close","Content-Length":"359","Content-Type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","Date":"Thu, 13 Mar 2014 19:23:12 GMT","Server":"Apache"},"text":"TIMESTAMP=2014%2d03%2d13T19%3a23%3a12Z&CORRELATIONID=ca98a083b004e&ACK=Failure&VERSION=93&BUILD=10030158&L_ERRORCODE0=10314&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Masspay%20input%20parse%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=The%20input%20to%20the%20masspay%20server%20is%20incorrect%2e%20Please%20make%20sure%20that%20you%20are%20using%20a%20correctly%20formatted%20input%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error","buffer":[84,73,77,69,83,84,65,77,80,61,50,48,49,52,37,50,100,48,51,37,50,100,49,51,84,49,57,37,51,97,50,51,37,51,97,49,50,90,38,67,79,82,82,69,76,65,84,73,79,78,73,68,61,99,97,57,56,97,48,56,51,98,48,48,52,101,38,65,67,75,61,70,97,105,108,117,114,101,38,86,69,82,83,73,79,78,61,57,51,38,66,85,73,76,68,61,49,48,48,51,48,49,53,56,38,76,95,69,82,82,79,82,67,79,68,69,48,61,49,48,51,49,52,38,76,95,83,72,79,82,84,77,69,83,83,65,71,69,48,61,77,97,115,115,112,97,121,37,50,48,105,110,112,117,116,37,50,48,112,97,114,115,101,37,50,48,101,114,114,111,114,38,76,95,76,79,78,71,77,69,83,83,65,71,69,48,61,84,104,101,37,50,48,105,110,112,117,116,37,50,48,116,111,37,50,48,116,104,101,37,50,48,109,97,115,115,112,97,121,37,50,48,115,101,114,118,101,114,37,50,48,105,115,37,50,48,105,110,99,111,114,114,101,99,116,37,50,101,37,50,48,80,108,101,97,115,101,37,50,48,109,97,107,101,37,50,48,115,117,114,101,37,50,48,116,104,97,116,37,50,48,121,111,117,37,50,48,97,114,101,37,50,48,117,115,105,110,103,37,50,48,97,37,50,48,99,111,114,114,101,99,116,108,121,37,50,48,102,111,114,109,97,116,116,101,100,37,50,48,105,110,112,117,116,37,50,101,38,76,95,83,69,86,69,82,73,84,89,67,79,68,69,48,61,69,114,114,111,114],"cookies":{}}}

Comment: Looks like you need to read about what json is

Comment: Agreed.  So, using httpResponse.status, I'm able to get that status=200 for each of these.  I just don't know how to pull ACK=Success out of .text.....